# Aurelia Bundle - How to bundle with bower dependencies?

Tags: aurelia

I followed this blog post: http://blog.durandal.io/2015/06/23/bundling-an-aurelia-application/ to bundle aurelia apps using the aurelia-cli.

Now the issues is that my project has bower dependencies and when I run `aurelia bundle` I get the error `Error: Cannot find module 'jspm-bower-endpoint'`

My config.js has this under paths:

`"paths": {
    "*": "/medik-app/dist/*.js",
    "github:*": "/medik-app/jspm_packages/github/*.js",
    "npm:*": "/medik-app/jspm_packages/npm/*.js",
    "bower:*": "/medik-app/jspm_packages/bower/*.js"
  }`

Comment: FYI The article referenced now points to a more recent version : http://blog.durandal.io/2015/09/11/bundling-aurelia-apps/